# Games do not use the nvidia gpu to run

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I updated the nvidia driver version to 535.154 from previous version and now my games not using the nvidia gpu. Strange thing is, nvidia-smi command works and drivers are installed properly. But i guess the applications refuses to run with nvidia for some reason. What can i do? My OS is Ubuntu 23.10

Comment: Have you rebooted the computer since the update of the video driver?

Comment: Are we talking Steam games? There's a settings toggle to use preferred GPU which I have seen get confused, just change it.  On laptops, env vars may control how the GPUs are used, and sometimes that gets reversed. Fix by runing progs with: __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <progtorun>

Comment: I rebooted the system many times. Tried different kernels from xanmod and official ubuntu generic kernels. This problem seems to affect heroic and lutris games only. Heroic as a flatpak and Lutris as a latest .deb package. Ghostrunner in Heroic used to run with 144 fps but now it gives nearly 10-12 fps. Elden Ring in Lutris is not started at all. The game stuck in loading screen.